# Retrieving multiple objects from a list based on two properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects that have three properties (name, severity, and number of occurrences).  I need to retrieve all names that match the highest severity, and then the highest occurrences within that severity.

So given a list such as:

```c#
Name:   Sev:   Occ:
Foo     3      2
Bar     2      3
Foobar  2      3
```

I would expect to get back Foo.

Given a list such as:

```c#
Name:   Sev:   Occ:
Foo     3      3
Bar     3      3
Foobar  2      4
```

I would expect to get back Foo *and* Bar.

I suppose it's important to note I only need the names returned, and as the list of objects is relatively small, I'm not concerned with multiple loops... except that this will run each time a value is changed on the form.

I admit my linq-fu is woefully inadequate.  So far I have tried using morelinq and making two passes...

```c#
 List<Offenders> offenderList = new List<Offenders>();

// offenderList.Add appropriate data objects

var offSev = offenderList.MaxBy(x => x.Severity);
var offOcc = offSev.MaxBy(x => x.Occurrence);
```

My hope was to have a list (offOcc) that had only the records I wanted, and then I could iterate through the .Names property for the report.  Instead, what I get is an error: 'Offenders' does not contain a definition for 'MaxBy' on the second statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first statement to this:

```
var offSev = offenderList.MaxBy(x => x.Severity).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Offenders> offenderList = new List<Offenders>() {
                new Offenders() { name = "Foo", sev = 3, occ = 3},
                new Offenders() { name = "Bar", sev = 3, occ = 3},
                new Offenders() { name = "Foobar", sev = 2, occ = 4}
            };

            var results = offenderList.GroupBy(x => new { x.sev, x.occ }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.sev).ThenByDescending(x => x.Key.occ).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",results.Select(x => x.name).ToArray()));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Offenders
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int sev { get; set; }
        public int occ { get; set; }
    }

}
```